# Flutter Updating an Image Inside showDialog Function After a User Chooses a New Image

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to be able to use an AlertDialog widget after a button is clicked to show either a blank space for an image or the actual image once a user selects it. Below is my code. Currently, the code begins correctly. It shows a blank space whenever the button is clicked and shows the Add IconButton to get the user to select an image. However once the user selects an image, the image does not display. It is only after you click the `OK` or `Cancel` button and then click the original button that the image shows up that was previously selected.

How can I edit the code to update the image immediately after a user selects one and clear it whenever the Add `IconButton` is called again?

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestyMcTesterson extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestyMcTesterson({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestyMcTesterson> createState() => _TestyMcTestersonState();
}

class _TestyMcTestersonState extends State<TestyMcTesterson> {
  PlatformFile? _imageFile;

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.image,
    );

    //return nothing if they don't choose an image
    if (result == null) return;

    //update the image to display with what the user selected
    setState(
      () {
        _imageFile = result.files.first;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _displayCorrectImage() {
    if (_imageFile != null) {
      return Image.memory(
        Uint8List.fromList(_imageFile!.bytes!),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      );
    } else {
      return const SizedBox();
    }
  }

  String? valueText;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () {
        showDialog(
          context: (context),
          builder: (context) {
            return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setState) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  content: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: _displayCorrectImage(),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: _pickImage,
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.photo),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    MaterialButton(
                      child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      child: const Text('OK'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I tried isolating each widget to determine that the showDialog function is causing the issue. Just returning the AlertBuilder instead of wrapping it in the IconButton and StatefulBuilder widgets allows this to work. Unfortunately, that's not what I need.

I've read into the showDialog function https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a small issue, i will just remind you the `setState` of the statefull widget will not update any ui in the `showdialog` so what you need to do is just pass the `setState` to your `_pickImage` function so that you could pass the setState of the statefullbuilder when you call`_pickImage` and that should work fine

here is the the copy and past code

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestyMcTesterson extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestyMcTesterson({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestyMcTesterson> createState() => _TestyMcTestersonState();
}

class _TestyMcTestersonState extends State<TestyMcTesterson> {
  PlatformFile? _imageFile;

  Future<void> _pickImage({required void Function(void Function()) setState_}) async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.image,
    );

    //return nothing if they don't choose an image
    if (result == null) return;

    //update the image to display with what the user selected
    setState_(
      () {
        _imageFile = result.files.first;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _displayCorrectImage() {
    if (_imageFile != null) {
      return Image.memory(
        Uint8List.fromList(_imageFile!.bytes!),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      );
    } else {
      return const SizedBox();
    }
  }

  String? valueText;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () {
        showDialog(
          context: (context),
          builder: (context) {
            return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setState) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  content: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: _displayCorrectImage(),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: _pickImage(setState_:setState),
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.photo),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    MaterialButton(
                      child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      child: const Text('OK'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :D Kudos

Comment: This worked! Only one change needed: I had to change the onPressed: _pickImage(setState_:setState), line to onPressed: () => _pickImage(setState_: setState), and then it ran perfectly. I appreciate it jasjastone!